# Basic Tex how to install packages?

Tags: packages, linux

I just installed Basic Tex and now of course I need to install additional packages. I tried

```
 tlmgr install <pkg>
```

But I get the error message:

```
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/tlpkg/ is not writable...
```

Do I need to add something to the path for this to work? And what would I need to add, I figured one of these:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/bin/x86_64-darwin
/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/bin/universal-darwin
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome so TeX.SE. What is the right on `/usr/local` on your system?

Comment: Are you root when trying to install then?

Comment: Ok so I need to install using sudo? Is there no way around this, sorry if the question is stupid, I'm not very familiar with this stuff @RomainPicot

Comment: On a linux system, if you don't have the permission on a folder you can't "use" it. So yes you have to install it as root here. Perhaps you can install it in another folder too where your non-root user have the permission (I don't know how)

Answer (score 1):

It's that you don't have the permission to use the folder `/usr/local` as non-root user. So you should use `tlmgr` as root.

For more information on permission on linux system, you can look at [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)